# Remove all elements of a list that are substrings of other elements of the list in python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the following list:

```
people = ['John', 'Maurice Smith', 'Sebastian', 'Maurice', 'John Sebastian', 'George', 'George Washington']
```

As you can notice, `John`, `Maurice`, `Sebastian` and `George` are names or last names of the full names (`Maurice Smith`, `Jogn Sebastian` and `George Washington`).

I would like to get only the full names. Is this possible in python?

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove them with this list comprehension:

```
[p for p in people if not any(p in p2 for p2 in people if p != p2)]
```

This iterates over each person `p`, then checks the condition:

```
not any(p in p2 for p2 in people if p != p2)
```

This inner loop iterates over each person `p2` (skipping the case where it is the same as `p`), and checks `p in p2` (whether `p` is a substring).

Comment: This performs a full search of the entire list for every item in it, and develops odd quirks if one of the long names happens to be within another one.

Comment: @kindall a) Yes. Is there a faster algorithm available (faster than n^2)? b) This fits the OP's requirement precisely (as stated in the title). If a long name is contained in another one, it will remove the former.

Comment: @kindall Certainly an algorithm could store a dictionary with every possible substring of each element. I doubt that would improve performance across most practical list lengths, and very much doubt it would be worth the increase in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
# make set of first names from full names
firstnames = set(name.split[0] for name in people if " " in name)

# get names that aren't in the above set
people[:] = (name for name in people if name not in firstnames)
```